# android duplicate dependencies and exclude don't work

Tags: android

after I applied this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0'
    compile files('libs/google-http-client/libs/google-http-client-android-1.20.0.jar')
    {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient' //by both name
    }
}
```

Here comes the error:

> Error:(30, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'exclude()'
>
> Possible causes:
>
> - The project 'Seeingeye' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method. Open Gradle wrapper file
> - The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin

**Update:**

It is solved by changing to :

```
 compile ('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }
```

but throws another error when building:

- Warning:  Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is
  ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version
  provided by Android.
           In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
- Warning:  Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is
  ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal
  version provided by Android.
              In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages

  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

which seems the previous problem was not properly solved.
Any thoughts?

**Update Solved**

double checked the build.gradle for the module app,
need to add

"multiDexEnabled true" to the defaultConfig block:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.huayiguo.seeingeye"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Though I'm glad you've managed to solve the issue, your solution feels to me more like a workaround that could cause troubles in the future. My guess in regards is that you've still had trouble left with HttpClient cause you left the google-http-client-android.jar under libs/google-http-client/libs/. Please see if deleting it solves the issues without enabling multi-dexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
    compile ('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it does solve the previous problem but throws another one:

Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages